# Email Sending Duplicate

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send email using SMTP, I found out that the email send duplicates, usually it sends more than 3 at same time, it makes me confused because it does not occur when I use Firefox. When I use chrome and/or opera it always sends double email.

Comment: Can you provide us more information about the library you are using to send emails, and the script which actually uses the library?

Comment: Can you provide more info on how are you exactly sending the emails?

Answer (score 1):

Please keep one thing in mind while working with SMTP for email sending functionality if you refresh your web browser again, your mail will be sent to the recipient.